# how to convert existence angular 7 project to android apk file

Tags: angular, cordova

i have an angular project which i want to convert it for android is there any way to do this i am using cordova and run this command npm install -g cordova after this when i run command cordova create MyApp i have got error

```
cordova : The term 'cordova' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or  
operable program. Check the  
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ cordova create mobile
+ ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cordova:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

is there any solution or any other way to covert angular to apk file

Comment: You can convert your angular app into IONIC and then you can build app for android       or IOS using cordova . Since IONIC is using angular for development it is very easy to migrate.

Comment: without IONIC  i want to do this

Comment: use the steps described in https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted. After copy your dist files in the www folder

Comment: i have install cordova golbaly but when i type cordova in command it,s give me error unrecognize cordova externa or internal command